# Bland Altman plot interpretation

Tags: bland-altman-plot

Dear all and good day,

Could please someone help me clarify what does it mean for the lower limit of the BA plot to be positive.

In most of the BA plots I saw, the limit ranges from -ve to -ve number but mine both upper and lower limits are +ve (1.2 to 3.8).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the Cross Validated [info page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/bland-altman-plot/info) on the Bland-Altman (or Tukey mean-difference) plot:

> The Bland-Altman plot consists in plotting the difference between the two assays against the mean of the two assays on each sample.

If the lower limit of the plot is greater than 0, then one of your assays is always providing larger values than the other.